# Integrability in Fubini's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

[Fubini' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) says

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are complete measure spaces with measures $\mu$ and $\nu$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is $A \times B$ measurable. If
>   $$
>     \int_{A\times B} |f(x,y)|\,\text{d}(\mu \times \nu)<\infty,
> $$
>   where the integral is taken with respect to a product measure on the space over $A \times B$, then
>   $$
>     \int_A\left(\int_B f(x,y)\,\text{d}\nu\right)\,\text{d}\mu=\int_B\left(\int_A f(x,y)\,\text{d}\mu\right)\,\text{d}\nu=\int_{A\times B} f(x,y)\,\text{d}(\mu \times \nu), $$

I was wondering if

- $f(x,) \in L^1(B), \forall x \in A$?
- $\int_B f(x,y) d\nu \in L^1(A)$ ?
- the reason $A$ and $B$ are **complete** measure spaces?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94486/fubinis-theorem-without-completeness-or-sigma-finiteness-conditions) on MathOverflow for a discussion on sigma-finiteness and completeness of the measure space.

In general you can't say that $f(x,\cdot)\in \mathcal{L}^1(B)$ for all $x\in A$ but only that
$$
\{x\in A\mid f(x,\cdot)\notin\mathcal{L}^1(B)\}
$$
is a measurable (with respect to the sigma-algebra on $A$) null-set. As to the second item:
$$
\int_A\left|\int_B f(x,y)\nu(\mathrm dy)\right|\mu(\mathrm dx)\leq \int_A\int_B|f(x,y)\nu(\mathrm dy)|\,\mu(\mathrm dx)=\int_{A\times B}|f(x,y)|\,\mathrm d(\mu\times \nu)<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks! is the set "measurable null set" $\{x∈A∣ f(x,⋅)∈ L^1(B)\}$ or $\{x∈A∣ f(x,⋅)\notin L^1(B)\}$?

Comment: It's the last one - edited accordingly :)

Comment: And, of course, proof of the fact that this null set is measurable requires completeness of the measure $\mu$...

Comment: @GEdgar: It does?